# Moon is not abstract

Tags: java

So I have a class named Moon which implements two interfaces Inhabitable, and Orbitable, both with two abstract methods. In my class moon I override both of the abstract methods. Orbitable is giving me no errors however Inhabitable is. This is the error.

```
1 error found:
File: /personalFilename/ [line: 1]
Error: Moon is not abstract and does not override abstract method chanceOfLife(int) in Inhabitable
```

the moon class

```
public class Moon extends Planet implements Inhabitable, Orbitable
{
  public Moon()
  {
    super();
  }

  public void orbitSpeed(int speed)
  {
    this.setDistance((speed / 6.28) * 8760);
  }

  public void chanceOflife(int oxygen)
  {
    this.setOxygenLevels(oxygen);
  }

}
```

the orbital interface

```
public interface Orbitable
{
  public abstract void orbitSpeed(int speed);
}
```

the Inhabitable interface

```
public interface Inhabitable
{
  public abstract void chanceOfLife(int oxygen);
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as a typographical error

Comment: As a matter of course, use the `@Override` annotation to indicate methods which you think override other methods. The compiler will sharp tell you if they don't.

Comment: `chanceOflife` != `chanceOfLife`: `l` != `L`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`chanceOfLife(int oxygen)` is not `chanceOflife(int oxygen)`, it is capital L.

There are a couple of things you need to be clear when override a method although it is just a typo:

You have to have the identical **method signature**(method name and parameters)when you override a method.

You don't have to put `public abstract` in interface methods. all methods in interface are public and abstract by default.

Based on Hovercraft Full Of Eels's comment, when you override a method, use `Override`, it would check whether the overridden is okay.

Comment: I was expecting to downvote you because come on, it's an answer to a typo, but this is actually a very informative answer. Good job.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks Mad.  When we are clear about basic concepts and it would reduce the typo :)

Comment: Better if you also mention relevant info about using `@Override` and how it can help.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for mentioning that, I added it to my post

Comment: @HaifengZhang dude i feel so dumb but in my defense l and L look very similar in drjava which is what I am using. If i was using eclipse which is what I should be using I probably would have seen it.